# SG6841 based SMPS output droops on load

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, repair

I am repairing an Elo Touch monitor ET1515L which, happily, has dual mains and 12V inputs. It works when powered from 12V supply but struggles on mains. I see sets of capacitors for the PSU board advertised on eBay but that doesn't seem to be my problem.

The AC circuit is almost directly from the SG6841 datasheet schematic: http://www.sg.com.tw/semiGP/data/6841/IRO33.0001.B5_SG6841V2.1.pdf page 11.

On power-up the SMPS delivers about 12V to the low-voltage section of the board (same as DC input) but when I touch the power button to wake up the monitor I get a brief blink on the backlight and the DC voltage drops to about 10.5V. I've disconnected the backlight inverter board to no effect.

So, the control is switching; high-voltage DC capacitor voltage remains stable on switch-on; feedback seems to be working; the transformer has a single secondary winding which seems OK and the Schottky rectifier tests OK on both legs.

What can cause this symptom on this type of SMPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for breaks in traces or lifted pads, check the output filter capacitor ESR (probably a prime suspect), and the current sense resistor (source resistor on the MOSFET) value.

Comment: I hadn't considered poor ESR at all. I found an article "99 cent ESR tester" (http://members.ozemail.com.au/~bobpar/99_Cent_ESR.pdf) which would be good enough for me. I'll try it out over the next few days.
Am I correct in thinking that high ESR would cause the output capacitor voltage to rise quickly, shutting off the switcher prematurely and leaving the capacitor under-charged for the load current - hence the voltage would fall?

Comment: Fixed. I found a 10uF 50V CapXon somewhere after the SMPS had no capacitance. I can't figure out what it's doing but replacing it has got the monitor going. Thanks for suggesting ESR. I had never used the testing technique before and it will be of great help in future. Anyone else interested should note the 99 cent ESR (in comment above) and there's a good tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=115erzCCxgE.

Answer (score 0):

If the SMPS was ever subjected to multiple overloads you may want to check if the THER1 component in the schematic is present in your design. If this indeed a polyfuse type component these can develop a higher than normal resistance after they have been tripped multiple times.

The BOM included with the schematic describes THER1 to be a thermistor. It is possible that it too may have developed a higher than normal resistance.

Comment: I considered that but ruled it out by comparing the mains voltage on the input and that on the bridge. Both the same and no significant drop on turning on the monitor. Thanks.